# UITableView shows rows in right order only during first run

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I made test app https://github.com/Aitbaev/iOS2 In this app there are 3 ViewControllers

1. Groups of people(UITableView)
2. People names(UITableView)
3. People details (whatever)

Groups must always be 3, 10-15 people names for each group are randomly taken from array of strings during the first run and are inserted into the  Core Data store. After the first run, application fills tables are only load from coredata (without groups generating). The problem is that UITableView on the second tableView shows rows in right order only during first run. after the first run,

if user goes back from
2)People names to 1)Groups

and then goes again to 
2)People names,

People names are the same but not in same order, and it happens after first run. during first run, everything is ok.

Comment: you can sort people names array alphabetically before displaying it in people names table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `['studentsInGroup' allObjects]` in `NamesViewController.m` provides no guarantee that the objects will return in the same order, since `NSSet` is an unordered collection of objects.

To sort the students associated with the `Group` object, and thereby guarantee the same order every time the view appears, you could call the following on your group of students:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"studentsNames" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [studentsInGroup sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

So I think it would be placed in your `getStudentsForRowMethod:` , so the final code would look like this:

```
-(Students*)getStudentForRow:(NSInteger)row{
    NSArray* arrayOfStudents = [self.group.studentsInGroup allObjects];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"studentsNames" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayOfStudents sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    return [arrayOfStudents objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Also you may want to perform the sort in `viewDidLoad` or in an override of the `group` property's getter, so the sort won't be performed every time you need to access the ordered collection of students.